# Do I need to create a module for: A user account, to create and save custom "objects" made of choices from a form

Tags: forms, drupal, web-applications, module

I used Drupal for 2 years, building some quiet "standard" sites (mainly "static content", no user logging etc.)
I always found the modules I needed for what I was expecting for (Views, Slideshows etc….)

In the next weeks, I have to build a little more complex project and I wonder if I can achieve it quiet easily with Drupal.
Until yet I never been through the drupal API, neither did I create a module.

But I'm a C++ developer, and I think there is no problem for me to learn rapidly how works an API.
I've been through the Drupal.org tutorial on how to create a Module (module "current_posts"), and I understood the global mechanisms

In the next weeks, I have to build a site with a little more complex parts, and I wonder how to achieve it with Drupal:

**The site is compound of:**

- a "classical section", with contents, videos, etc…
- a user section

**The user section give a user the possibility to:**

1. Create an account
2. fill a form to create an custom "object". The object is compound of 5 parts for example. And each part as several possibilities. 
   Example: Part 1 -> Options A, B, C, D, E,     Part 2 -> Option aa, bb, cc, dd etc...
3. save his object to a collection
4. fill a second form to give extras infos about the object he has just created
5. save these extras infos
6. get some custom infos "built" upon the choices he made in section 2) and 4)
7. relog later and reload the objects he built previously

**I wonder if:**

- it can be achieved only with existing modules?
- …or do I need to develop a custom module?
- Do i need although to create some custom Tables in the DB,
- …or is it possible to deal only with content types
- Do I need to "design" the tables interactions on a paper, like a real DB developer ;).

Is there some special things I should be careful with? Do you have some clues about how to realize this?
And does it seems feasible in a short delay?

And last but not least;) Is Drupal a really good solution for such a project?

Thanx in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi,What does the classical section do?Can a user build more that one object

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is great for such a project. And you don't need too much extra modules, just core modules.

1) Core user module is fine.

2) Node type A. Create the node with the described fields and a user Role that will be able to add new A nodes as also as edit/delete own A nodes.

4) Node type B. Just add relationship for the Node type A so users can make the connection. Use the [EntityReference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module here. Similar user role permissions here.

6) This needs more information but it seems you need to use Views module to achieve this.

7) Welcome to Drupal! This is a core functionality also.